# Delete all rows not containing substring in column using InStr

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to reduce my table to all rows which have "X" as substring in the second column. 
For that I wrote the following:

```
Sub reduce()
   Dim lngRow As Long

    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        lngRow = .Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Do
            pos = InStr(.Cells(lngRow, 2), "X")

            If Not pos > 0 Then

                .Rows(lngRow).Delete

            End If


            lngRow = lngRow - 1
        Loop Until lngRow = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Unfortunately I get this error: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/application-defined-or-object-defined-error

Comment: A `For Each` loop coupled with a `Union` deletion may help speed things along. The larger your range becomes, the better this solution will be due to gains on row deletions

Comment: Why not just use a filter here? Text Filter - does not contain "X" - delete all visible cells. Much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

How to do this in a loop. Its more code but more efficient than current method. @BigBen is correct that a filter is optimal given current problem statement

```
Sub Reduce()


'Declare variables
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update Sheet
Dim LR As Long
Dim xCell As Range, xRange As Range
Dim DeleteMe As Range


'Assign/Set necessarry variables
LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set xRange = ws.Range("A2:A" & LR)


'Create Union (Collection Of Rows) to Delete
For Each xCell In xRange
    If Not InStr(xCell.Offset(0, 1), "X") Then
        If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteMe = Union(xCell, DeleteMe)
        Else
            Set DeleteMe = xCell
        End If
    End If
Next xCell


'Delete the Union
If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
    DeleteMe.EntireRow.Delete
End If

End Sub
```